# Google SEO tool that shows search questions based on keywords?

Tags: seo, google, keywords

An SEO told me that he recently read of a Google SEO tool that shows actual QUESTIONS (rather than queries = Google keyword tool) that are typed into Google, based on the keywords one enters. Unfortunately, he could not remember the name of the tool nor where it was that linked to it.

Since I run a Q&A site, such a tool would be extremely valuable to me for keyword optimization. Does anyone know of such a tool, or anything that is similar?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This person might have been referring to [WordTracker's Questions Tool](https://freekeywords.wordtracker.com/questions).

Comment: I'm not sure if he was or not, but this was an awesome suggestion, thank you.

Comment: Out of interest, do you subscribe to any of Wordtracker's paid tools? Have you found them useful if so?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that entire question is relevance of WordTracker Key Word Tool. Go through wordtracker key phrase tool